# How can I list files in exFAT file system from image file?

Tags: exfat

I have created a disk image using FKT Imager of a USB stick with exFAT partition. I want to make a list of all folders and files on the image.

My exFAT starts at LBA=6146048 with Sector size=512 that gives me offset=3146776576. Below is a screenshot of the exFAT Main Boot Region with *RootDirectoryCluster* in red as described at
https://www.ntfs.com/exfat-boot-sector.htm.

- 96 (0x60)    4   RootDirectoryCluster

**exFAT Main Boot Region**
[image]
So from here I get this:
firstClusterOfRootDirectoryDec=4 HexLittleEndian = 04000000 HexBigEndian=00000004

However when I look at the offset 4 clusters below I only see 0's. My offset is then (6146048*512)+(4*512)=3146778624.

[image]